# Deleted my App.xml and App.xml.cs files

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012

Stupidly, I deleted my App.xml and App.xml.cs files by mistake.

I am able to recreate these files as I use source control (a bit out of date, regrettably), however when I recreate these files and add them back into my project, VS cannot build the project because I'm informed I don't have an entry point.

My workaround is to create a loading class with a 'Main' keyword for application entry and associate is with the project, however what is the correct procedure for recreating and re-associating my App.xml and App.xml.cs files in VS in my project.

Many thanks.

Comment: You should also restore your `.csproj` file from source control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question intrigued me, so I created a new project and blew away the `App.xaml` and `App.xaml.cs` files. I then added a window to the project and changed its Build Action in the File Properties editor to `ApplicationDefinition` from `Page`, I then changed the `xaml` and the `xaml.cs` files to the Application Class. After which it worked correctly.

i.e.

**App.xaml**

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication1.App"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

**App.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;


namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for App.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class App : Application 
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Pretty sure the questioner's problem is fixed by changing the type from `Page` to `ApplicationDefinition`.

Comment: "ApplicationDefinition" was the key here. Thanks

Comment: Sometimes changing the build action is not enough. If you start from a new window you need to create both files as above and also change the build action.